# jQuery bind three select menus hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have three select menus.

```
<form>
  <select id="mass" name="mass">
    <option value="Blank" selected>--</option>
    <option value="Light">Light</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Heavy">Heavy</option>
  </select>
  <select id="colour" name="colour">
    <option value="Blank" selected>--</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select id="textureColour" name="textureColour">
    <option value="Blank" selected>--</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I want the first menu to display, and the second and third menus to be hidden, until called upon.

If the first menu changes from the default option, I want the second menu to display.

Once a selection has been made within the second menu, I want the third menu to display.

However, I only want the third menu to display, if the selected value in the first menu is either 'Medium' or 'Heavy'. Selecting the default 'Blank' or 'Light' should hide the third menu.

Currently it isn't functioning as I would I like.

```
$(function() {
  var mass = $('#mass');
  var colour = $('#colour');
  var textureColour = $('#textureColour');

  mass.change(function() {
    if (mass.val() != 'Blank') {
      $(colour).show();
    } else {
      $(colour).hide();
    }
    if (mass.val() === 'Light') {
      $(textureColour).show();
    } else {
      $(textureColour).hide();
    }
  }).trigger('change');

  colour.change(function() {
    if ((mass.val() === 'Medium') || (mass.val() === 'Heavy')) {
      $(textureColour).show();
    } else {
      $(textureColour).hide();
    }
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvanstan/qd15hkfr/1/)

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/qd15hkfr/2/

Comment: No, as I want the third menu to hide if I change the value from 'Medium' or 'Heavy' back to 'Light'.

Answer (score 1):

So, I guess that you want something like this

```js
$(function() {
  var mass = $('#mass');
  var colour = $('#colour');
  var textureColour = $('#textureColour');

  mass.change(function() {
    if (mass.val() != 'Blank') {
      $(colour).show();
      $(colour).change();
    } else {
      $(colour).val('Blank');
      $(textureColour).val('Blank');
      $(colour).hide();
      $(textureColour).hide();
    }
  });

  colour.change(function() {
    if ((mass.val() === 'Medium') || (mass.val() === 'Heavy') && colour.val() !== 'Blank') {
      $(textureColour).show();
    } else {
      $(textureColour).hide();
      
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#colour {
  display: none;
}

#textureColour {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="mass" name="mass">
    <option value="Blank" selected>--</option>
    <option value="Light">Light</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Heavy">Heavy</option>
  </select>
  <select id="colour" name="colour">
    <option value="Blank" selected>--</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select id="textureColour" name="textureColour">
    <option value="Blank" selected>--</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That helped, but I fixed the line for the 'Medium' and 'Heavy'. https://jsfiddle.net/jvanstan/qd15hkfr/4/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forget to write `$(colour).hide();` and `$(textureColour).hide();` instead of `$(colour).hide;` and `$(textureColour).hide;`.

**EDIT**

I had to change complete your code. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
$(function() {
  var mass = $('#mass');
  var colour = $('#colour');
  var textureColour = $('#textureColour');

  mass.change(function() {

  if(mass.val() == 'Blank'){
    colour.hide();
    textureColour.hide();
  }else{
    colour.show();
    if(colour.val() != 'Blank') textureColour.show();
  }

  if(mass.val() == 'Light') textureColour.hide();
  }).trigger('change');

  colour.change(function() {
    if(colour.val() == 'Blank') return textureColour.hide();
    if('Medium,Heavy'.split(',').indexOf(mass.val()) != -1){
    textureColour.show();
    }
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I've updated my code. But it still doesn't work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the javascript and now it is functioning how I wanted it too:

```
$(function() {
  var mass = $('#mass');
  var colour = $('#colour');
  var textureColour = $('#textureColour');

  mass.change(function() {
    if (mass.val() != 'Blank') {
      $(colour).show();
      $(colour).change();
    } else {
      $(colour).val('Blank');
      $(textureColour).val('Blank');
      $(colour).hide();
      $(textureColour).hide();
    }
  });

  colour.change(function() {
    if (((mass.val() === 'Medium') && colour.val() !== 'Blank') || ((mass.val() === 'Heavy') && colour.val() !== 'Blank')) {
      $(textureColour).show();
    } else {
      $(textureColour).hide();

    }
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvanstan/qd15hkfr/4/)